# How to use ATL Soap Client over SSL connection

Tags: c++, web-services, ssl, atl

I have to write a client that connects to a web service over SSL. I'd been planning to use ATL Soap Client for this (those classes generated by msvs2005 when right clicking on project->add web reference) however those classes seem to be unable to connect to the server over SSL.

When I try to send a request, it fails here:

```
// default only supports HTTP
return scheme == ATL_URL_SCHEME_HTTP ? true : false;
```

And the stack trace is:

> MyClientDll.dll!ATL::ZEvtSyncSocket::SupportsScheme(ATL::ATL_URL_SCHEME scheme=ATL_URL_SCHEME_HTTPS)  Line 355 C++
>
> MyClientDll.dll!ATL::CAtlHttpClientT::_SetDefaultUrl(const char * szURL=0x00000000, short nPort=443)  Line 2269 + 0x15 bytes  C++
>
> MyClientDll.dll!ATL::CAtlHttpClientT::SetDefaultUrl(const ATL::CUrl * pUrl=0x0012beac, short nPortNumber=443)  Line 1126  C++
>
> MyClientDll.dll!ATL::CAtlHttpClientT::Navigate(const ATL::CUrl * pUrl=0x0012beac, ATL::ATL_NAVIGATE_DATA * pData=0x0012babc)  Line 161 + 0x1a bytes   C++
>
> MyClientDll.dll!ATL::CSoapSocketClientT::SendRequest(const char * szAction=0x0a369058)  Line 6667 + 0x1c bytes    C++

Anyone knows how to make this ATL Soap client support SSL?